# Rails server claims "No such file - ["config/database.yml"]" even though it is there

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

After developing in Rails on a virtual Linux machine, I just recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux. Before the Christmas weekend, it was working just fine, but as of this morning, when I try and start up my rails server, it gives me the following complaint:

`Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]`

Of course, when I go into my config folder, database.yml is there - just like it was last week. So I'm confused why it can't find the file now when it absolutely could find it before. Is this some sort of WSL quirk that makes the file hard to find for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely guesswork, but I assume that there is a permission issue. If `config/database.yml` has insufficient ownership or read-levels, it may not be found by your Rails application.

For further diagnose, I recommend posting the output of:

```
# Get permission details for your config
ls -laZ config/database.yml
```

And maybe some details of which user is starting the Rails application (effectively which user owns the Ruby process).